# Rounding Methods in IEEE

Tags: verilog, conversion, floating-point

I am trying to learn the features of IEEE rounding from the following source [On fast IEEE Rounding](ftp://reports.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/csl/tr/91/459/CSL-TR-91-459.pdf)

[image]
Can anyone one explain the equation for round up ? What does round up with fix up mean ? And what are floor and ceiling functions ? I tried IEEE 754 , but it does not mention these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Floor" and "ceiling" are functions that return the next or previous integral value to a specific float value, where "next" and "previous" are defined with reference to positive infinity. For instance, ⌊2.3⌋ = 2.0, while ⌈2.3⌉ = 3.0. Float values that happen to be an integral value are unaffected.

With that, we can see that "round up" gets the next integral value if the fractional component is 0.5 or greater, otherwise it gets the previous integral value. RU(2.3) = 2.0, while RU(2.7) = 3.0.

The "fix up" is explained in the paragraph after that table, but the definition is a bit erudite. In simple terms, it checks to see that not only if the fractional component is greater than 0.5 (G), but if 1) the integral component is an odd number (L=1) or an even number (L=0), and 2) if the fractional component is *exactly* equal to 0.5 (S = 0) or if it is greater than 0.5 (s = 1). In effect, RN *always* rounds to an even number unless it would be *specifically* closer to an odd number. RN(2.5) = 2.0, RN(2.7) = 3.0, RN(3.5) = 4.0.

Comment: So , [x] if x-[x]>= 0.5 is the ceiling function
     [x] otherwise is the floor function ?

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw No, you need to look more carefully at the included text. You are using the square brackets, but the symbols for ceiling and floor are slightly different. Perhaps that is the source of your confusion.

Comment: Yes , you are right ..It was the symbols

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can at least answer floor and ceiling functions:

```
number = 3.2
floor(number) = 3
ceiling(number) = 4

number = -3.2
floor(number) = -4
ceiling(number) = -3
```

Sorry for explaining this in a non-theoretical way.